# How to implement a friendship system in my database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, data-structures

I have a user system in my database and I want to adding the posibility of add friends.
The user have to be able to:

- Send a message in the petition
- Block user
- Set alias to friend user.

So I though this table:

```
id_friend
id_user1
id_user2
id_user_sender
alias_user1 NULL
alias user2 NULL
status
message NULL
date_sent
date_accepted NULL
```

I'm going to explain each colum:

- **id_friend**: PK of the table.
- **id_user1**: FK of users table
- **id_user2**: FK of users table
- **id_user_sender**: the id_user of who send the petition
- **alias_user1** NULL: the alias seted by id_user1 to id_user2 (optional)
- **alias user2** NULL: the alias seted by id_user2 to id_user1 (optional)
- **status** : if 0 friendship pendient. if 1 friends. if 2 friendship bloqued.
- **message** NULL: if status = 0 then can contain a message seted by the sender
- **date_sent**: date when sender sent the petition
- **date_accepted** NULL: date when user_requested acepted the friendship.

Then to get all the friends of a specific user I'll do:

```
select id_user1, id_user2 from friends where id_user1 = $my_user_id or id_user2 = $my_user_id and status = 1;
```

Then I'd discard the id_users equal to mine, so the result contains only the user who are my friends. But to get the alias I don't have any idea. May be with more tables?

I think I'm designing it wrong... Do you have any tip or advice? could you give some example please?

If you need more info let me know and I'll edit the post.

Comment: What's the difference between `alias_user1` and `alias_user2`?

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I've edited. Check it out! :) However, I thing I'd need more tables, at least to the user alias.

Comment: What do you want to do with the alias? Show it? Or search with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

some things that i would do:

1. you don't need id_user_sender. You can assume that the sender will be stored always in id_user1 and the other on id_user2
2. You can replace the status with a boolean called blocked. You can tell if the friendship is pending or not by checking if the date_accepted value is null

For getting the alias names of the friends of $my_user_id you can call this query

```
select case when id_user1=$my_user_id then alias_user2 else alias_user1 end
from friends
where id_user1=$my_user_id or id_user2=$my_user_id
```

Comment: Thanks, and imagine I want to select all friends with their sex field (which is in users table). How I can link the two tables? Any idea? Could you give me an example, please?

Comment: you could also add `case when id_user1=$my_user_id then id_user2 else id_user1 end` in the select clause to get the id of the friend. and then you could (left) join with the users table on users.id

Comment: So this could serve? `select u.id_sex
from friends f, users u
where u.id_usuario = case when f.id_user1=$my_user_id then f.id_user2 else f.id_user1 end
and f.id_user1 = $my_user_id or
f.id_user2 = $my_user_id;` Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
select id_user1, id_user2, alias_user2 from friends where id_user1 = $my_user_id or id_user2 = $my_user_id and status = 1;
```

Maybe this is what you are looking for.